# How can I reduce the size of this JSON record?

Tags: json, document-database

I'm working on reducing the size of my database records. Each record is on average around 5Kb of which 97% is used by an single array property.

This array describe object on an image and their bounding box, described as a series of points:

```json
[
    {
      "s": 0,
      "e": 6,
      "w": "Ihandle",
      "b": [
        { "x": 0.08816705336426914, "y": 0.1531684174855981 },
        { "x": 0.2523201856148492, "y": 0.15249068112504235 },
        { "x": 0.2523201856148492, "y": 0.17926126736699424 },
        { "x": 0.08816705336426914, "y": 0.17993900372754998 }
      ]
    },
    {
      "s": 8,
      "e": 16,
      "w": "financial",
      "b": [
        { "x": 0.08584686774941995, "y": 0.1762114537444934 },
        { "x": 0.25696055684454755, "y": 0.1762114537444934 },
        { "x": 0.25696055684454755, "y": 0.2016265672653338 },
        { "x": 0.08584686774941995, "y": 0.2016265672653338 }
      ]
    },
    {
      "s": 18,
      "e": 29,
      "w": "transactions",
      "b": [
        { "x": 0.016241299303944315, "y": 0.20060996272450016 },
        { "x": 0.25928074245939675, "y": 0.19959335818366655 },
        { "x": 0.25928074245939675, "y": 0.22636394442561844 },
        { "x": 0.016821345707656612, "y": 0.22738054896645205 }
      ]
    },

...
]
```

About these points:

- always exactly 4 points
- point not always parallel to each others
- doesn't require more than 1/1000 precision

I was wondering, is there a way I can reduce the size of that payload? (end goal is to index those record in full text search service like Algolia)

Answer (score 1):

- You can minify the JSON, which could save a little bit of space. You can still pretty-print it in a formatted way.
- If you don't need the full precision, you could remove some digits and shorten the numbers to something like "0.016821"
- A Bounding box could be expressed like this: Point(x,y) + Width + Height. That would be 4 Numbers instead of 8!

edit: What about those coordinates? Numbers look like they represent a fraction of the screen width and height (like a canvas). Sure, you can lower the precision, but if your resolution is fixed you could use Integer numbers. "1024, 800" has a lot less characters compared to "0.016821345707656612, 0.22738054896645205".